# A person or entity that decides how an obligation should be fulfilled

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, legalese

Let's say that I caused some nasty accident and someone was hurt and a judge told me that I have an obligation to amend their damage somehow.

However, some other person (or entity) will decide *how* these damages should be amended. E.g. paying the claimant 1000$ or helping mow their lawn for a month. What could this person be called in this context? Something more graceful than *damage-fulfilment-decider*.

Comment: Who's going to have the official word? The judge? The lawyers? An arbitrator? The insurance adjusters? Overseer?

Comment: The judge did his part: he said I am guilty (at least in this scenario). As for the way of amending the damages the person I am asking about will have the final word.

BTW it is of course a completely made-up story just to draw some context.

Comment: If you want something that revolves around `settlement`, I believe __mediator__ does the job. Technically, a mediator would attempt to reach an agreement prior to any litigation/serious court proceedings.

Answer (score 2):

Arbitrator or loss-adjuster are job titles which are used in the UK, do they fit what you want?

Comment: Arbitrator might be close to what I am looking for. However, it appears that it is more a person who settles a dispute. In the case I presented there is not so much a dispute if I should amend the damages rather than deciding how I can amend them

Comment: FYI it was not me who -1'ed you

Comment: The system has determined this is a low-quality answer -- hence the downvote -- probably because it's phrased as a question. When writing an asnwer, **write an answer.** Include corroborative examples (which need to be correctly referenced).

Comment: I love how you write "the system" to mean "a human being who has an account on this site".

Comment: What a strange "system" - as a newbie, I phrased my answer politely (as I thought) and the "system" marked me down.  Apparently if I had given a blunt answer that would have been OK - weird.

Comment: Well, "the system" decided it was being unnecessarily unfriendly, so "the system" just set you back to flat (best I can do, sorry: I've only one +1 to give). That said, "the system" would like to see your rephrase your answer as an affirmative statement, with link to a dictionary or glossary of insurance terms, or whatever, rather than a question. "The system" also wishes you a warm welcome and hopes you stick around awhile.

Comment: @Dan Bron - many thanks Dan, for the up-vote and the welcome!

Comment: The flag for a low-quality answer is raised automatically, and the downvote follows. I try to explain why it's happened. FWIW this answer is probably right; but some corroboration would be good, along with making it a statement. Answers in SE should answer the question: it's not a discussion forum (and neither are comments to be used for discussion, so we shouldn't be discussing voting/quality here).

Comment: The answer should be rewritten and provided with some additional supporting information. Otherwise, it could be converted to a comment by "the system". A more specific suggestion is that you address the OP's comment that this answer is inadequate.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind digging to the origin ([<sup><sub>Etymonline</sub></sup>](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=arbiter&searchmode=none)):

1. [**Arbiter**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arbiter) is a less pragmatic but more pompous title that stresses on the idea of calling a "final" and irrevocable decision. It is more akin to "judge" and often used as an exaggeration: `Well, you are not the arbiter of this dispute. Don't tell me what to do.`

   As you might suspect, arbiter has multiple derivatives e.g. arbitrate, arbitrary.
2. An alternative is **enforcer** with a hint of negativity and brawn.

Answer (score 1):

**Adjudicator** pops to mind from somewhere, or less formally, **referee**. As a mostly self-taught linguist and fellow newbie/61-year-old, I surely share Helen's hesitance at the need for corroboration--in many if not most cases it dissolves into "vast experience"...

Answer (score 0):

**Assessor** would be an appropriate term if you are strictly being ordered to remedy the other person's damages in strictly monetary terms. (In common law courts, this would almost certainly be the case.)

The noun "assessor" is not generally used to describe a person who does this (it is generally performed by the judge), but the phrase "assessment of damages" is used to describe the process of determining how much money should be paid. (See "The assessment of damages in accordance with applicable legal principles is a task for the tribunal of fact.", Halsbury's Laws of Australia 65(D)(1).)

Even if you want to refer to non-monetary obligations, I feel that the meaning of "assessor" could reasonably be expanded to include what you want to say.